# how does this php form work without defining variable?

Tags: php

how does this php form work without defining $SCRIPT_NAME variable ?

```
<form action="<?php echo $SCRIPT_NAME ?>" method="post">
```

Comment: Do you want the script itself to be called on form submittion?

Comment: If the variable has a value, that value is assigned *somewhere*. Maybe not right next to the form, but if you `grep` for `SCRIPT_NAME` you will definitely find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code relies on the ancient, deprecated and horrible `register_globals` feature which creates global variables from all the `$_REQUEST`, `$_COOKIE` and `$_SERVER` fields.

I'd highly suggest you to get rid of this code and disable the `register_globals` setting.

Answer (score 1):

There is a variable, $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] that prints out the name of the current script. You can find some information on it here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

I would suspect that is what is being used.

Comment: In which case, register_globals is probably enabled in the php configuration - generally a bad idea. It means you don't have to specifically reference some of the global variables (like $_SERVER) that PHP provides, but it can cause security problems: http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` will give you the relative path of the executing script, as well as the variable `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` gives the current script name.

An alternative would be to use `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` or the constant **FILE**, which each give the absolute path.

Those should be preferred and used instead of using the `register-globals` feature which should be disabled as @ThiefMaster said.